# TABLE WITH CUSTOMISED BORDER

Tags: html, css, list, html-table, css-tables

I am trying to add customised borders to a table with the columns set by bootstrap. The aim is to have the table like in the sketch attached.

Each row should have spacing between the top/bottom row border and also around the column border.

On hover the whole row is inverted and takes full width of the browser including the border above/below.

I've worked on a fiddle and can get slightly close:
https://jsfiddle.net/2020_RG/y47h3sbm/

Although the exact spacing I cannot figure out to get the borders like in the sketch. There must be a more elegant css solution to this.

Any help and suggestions would be incredible, thank you!

[image: desired list1]

Snippet here:

```css
/* Bootstrap Reset */

.row {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.table-bordered {
    border: none;
}

.table-bordered td, .table-bordered th {
    border: none;
}       

.table thead th {
    border-bottom: none !important;
}

.table thead th:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}

.table th, .table td {
    border-top: none !important;
}



/* CSS */

body {
  font-family; 'Helvetica';
  font-size:3vw;
}

.subHeading {
  font-size:1.5vw;
}


 
.table tr.row {
    padding: 0 1.2vw;
}

.table thead th {
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 55% !important; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}

 .cellContainer {
    display: block;
    width: 98%; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent !important;
 }
 
 .cell {
     display: block;
     margin: 5px 0;
     width: 101.2%;
     border-right: 1px solid black !important;
}


.link {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.link:hover {
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
    <table class="table">
        
        <thead>
            
            <tr class="row subHeading">
                <th class="col-md-4">
                    Author
                    </th>
                <th class="col-md-5">
                    Title
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-3">
                    Year
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
                                        
            <tr class="row link" data-href="#">
                <td class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">Alice Walker</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-5">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">The Color Purple</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">1982</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>       


            <tr class="row link" data-href="#">
                <td class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">Charlotte Brontë</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-5">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">Jane Eyre</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">1847</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>   


            <tr class="row link" data-href="#">
                <td class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">Virginia Woolf</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-5">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">Mrs. Dalloway</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">1925</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            
            <tr class="row link" data-href="#">
                <td class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">Toni Morrison</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-5">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">Beloved</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">1987</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>   
                                        
                    
            <tr class="row link" data-href="#">
                <td class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">Saul Frampton</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-5">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">When I Am Playing With My Cat, How Do I Know She Is Not Playing With Me?</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">2011</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            
            
                    
            <tr class="row link" data-href="#">
                <td class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">Miguel de Cervantes</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-5">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">Don Quixote</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-3">
                    <span class="cellContainer">
                        <span class="cell">1605</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>                       
                                        
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rq4upe89/), I've added some elements to your `thead` and styling to the `.cell` and `.cellContainer` classes.

Comment: Thanks! This is close. Is there a way the width for the cell can be set using the calc too and then define the spacing in a more clear way–like 10px between each column? 

I was struggling and had a bit of a hack by making the width more than 100%, although the calc seems like a better solution if its possible?  

+ is there a way the hover can include the border line too? Now it makes a gap from in the solid background which looks a bit odd. Thanks!

Comment: Still struggling with this one. Can anyone help so the hover fills in the gaps and include the border above and below? thanks!